# why results for php curl file upload method differs from html form file upload?

Tags: php, curl

I was working on some projects and suddenly I came up with this issue.
Consider having a file named `requestWithFile.htm` with the contents like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <form method="POST" action='http://127.0.0.1/pv.php' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="url" value="https://example.com/" /><br>
    <input type="file" name="myfile" /><br>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and another file which in php named `requestWithFile.php` which does the same job:

```
<?php
    $requesturl = "http://127.0.0.1/pv.php";
    $file = realpath('touploadfile.jpg');

    $ch = curl_init($requesturl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    "url" => "https://example.com/",
    "myfile" => "@".$file
    ));
    echo curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

My post parameters in both situations are:
`url` => `https://example.com/`
`myfile` => a file named `touploadfile.jpg`
which `touploadfile.jpg` file is in the same directory with both the html and the php files.

The `pv.php` file contains codes to display the requests that we have made. Those codes are:

```
<?php
    echo "The \$_POST :<br>\n\n";
    print_r($_POST); print "\n\n<br><br>";
    echo "The \$_GET :<br>\n\n";
    print_r($_GET); print "\n\n<br><br>";
    echo "The \$_REQUEST :<br>\n\n";
    print_r($_REQUEST); print "\n\n<br><br>";
    echo "The \$_FILES :<br>\n\n";
    print_r($_FILES); print "\n\n<br><br>";
    echo "The apache_request_headers: :<br>\n\n";
    print_r(apache_request_headers()); print "\n\n<br><br>";
?>
```

### NOW

If we make requests with the first file `requestWithFile.htm`, the browser echoes out:

```
The $_POST :
Array ( [url] => https://example.com/ )

The $_GET :
Array ( )

The $_REQUEST :
Array ( [url] => https://example.com/ )

The $_FILES :
Array ( [myfile] => Array ( [name] => touploadfile.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpB1B1.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 69 ) )

The apache_request_headers: :
Array ( [Host] => 127.0.0.1 [User-Agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0 [Accept] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 [Accept-Language] => en-US,en;q=0.5 [Accept-Encoding] => gzip, deflate [Referer] => http://127.0.0.1/requestWithFile.htm [Connection] => keep-alive [Content-Type] => multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------1848618309200 [Content-Length] => 377 )
```

but If we make the same request with `requestWithFile.php` file the result differs:

```
The $_POST :
Array ( [url] => https://example.com/ [myfile] => @C:\xampp\htdocs\touploadfile.jpg )

The $_GET :
Array ( )

The $_REQUEST :
Array ( [url] => https://example.com/ [myfile] => @C:\xampp\htdocs\touploadfile.jpg )

The $_FILES :
Array ( )

The apache_request_headers: :
Array ( [Host] => 127.0.0.1 [Accept] => */* [Content-Length] => 304 [Expect] => 100-continue [Content-Type] => multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------122eddaaad7fe29d )
```

Except the difference between headers (which is because of sending from a web browser in the html file) the question that comes to mind is:
**Why the value for $_FILES is empty for the php file?**
**Why the results for two identical requests differs ?**
I myself cant figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of PHP are you on? The @ syntax for file uploads is being dropped since 5.6. See the new one:

https://wiki.php.net/rfc/curl-file-upload

So basically it should look something like:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
  "url" => "https://example.com/",
  "myfile" => curl_file_create($file) // alias of new CURLFile($path)
));
```

Comment: its `7.0.3` ... but when I use your code another problem occurs. My code echoes no result on the page! It is empty now!

Comment: I changed the request url to somewhere and then back to 127.0.0.1 . for unknown reason Its OK now .